# Missing shorcuts newly installed applications Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xfce, menulibre

I just installed Xubuntu 14.04 Desktop then installed *Boot-Repair* and *Grub Customizer*
I don't see their shortcuts in menu. So what am I missing?
A lil bit detail:

- Application shortcuts exists in /usr/share/applications/
- Menu entries exist in file:///home/myuser/.config/menus/xfce-applications.menu
- I open MenuLibre window and can confirm entries exist for both of these apps I installed.
- Also I can run them with alt+f2 and via command prompt.

No Idea why I just can't see them in menu.
i.e I only see two items under System. But in MenuLibre window I see there are a lot of shortcuts.
Is there a way to rebuild menu shortcuts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Miraculously solved my problem.